# IBM MQ client compatibility

Tags: messaging, ibm-mq

Can a 7.5 ibm mq client dll run on MQ 6.x server (compatible with 6x MQ server) ?

I am going to implement get, put messages and few more. What objects will be supported (for ex: queue manager, queue instance etc)?

If it is not compatible, what 6.x version(64-bit complaint) of MQ client dll will be supportive in MQ 6.x version?

Any inputs will be highly helpful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to connect to MQ v6 queue manager using a higher version of MQ Client. But there are lot of differences between MQ v6 and MQ v7x queue manager. When you connect to MQ v6 queue manager all the features of MQ v7x will not be available. The notable feature is the native Pub/Sub and object like Topic. You can't use the MQ v7 native pub/sub API, MQSUB, MQSUBRQ to subscribe and MQPUT on topics.

You can use only those features that are available in MQ v6. You can do Put/Get to/from a queue and do Pub/Sub using the Queued interface.

Answer (score 1):

To focus on the last question; WMQ v6 is not a level that is currently supported. It would be recommended to move to the a version 7 WMQ installation.

Connections over a TCP/IP connection - rather than 'in-process' will negotiate the features that are available to the set that matches the QueueManager that is being connected to.

Answer (score 0):

You should double check with IBM Software Support if it's a supported configuration.